# Scala: Shift elements in an Array

Tags: arrays, scala

I'm getting used to the various data structures in Scala and I've noticed that this function (contrived example), which is supposed to move every character in the mutable array to the right by one, has no effect on the array:

```
  def shiftRight(str: String): Array[Char] = {
    val chars = str.toCharArray
    for(i <- chars.length - 1 until 0) chars(i) = chars(i - 1)
    chars
  }
  println(shiftRight("ABCD").mkString)
```

which produces the result

```
ABCD
```

not the expected

```
AABC
```

Comment: `until 0 by -1`

Comment: Or even better to use more explicit `i <- Range(start = chars.length - 1, end = 0, step = -1)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Default step for range is one. See class `Range` [here](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.8/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Range.scala#L443) and implicit that gets you to it [here](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.8/src/library/scala/runtime/RichInt.scala#L55).
Instead of

```
for(i <- chars.length - 1 until 0)...
```

you need:

```
for(i <- chars.length - 1 until 0 by -1)...
```